# Extend Parse.User

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Is it possible to extend Parse.User in CloudCode and add additional fields to it?

e.g. would the following work?

```
var AwesomeUser = Parse.User.extend({
    defaults: function () {
        return {
            fullname: 'Teddy Bear',
            is_awesome: false
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm petty sure that any changes made to the `User` class through cloud code need to use the master key.

```
Parse.Cloud.userMasterKey();
```

Comment: It essentially gives administrative permissions which I believe is required when modifying the "User" class

Comment: What exactly do you mean? If you mean "is parse good to have a user login and logout of the app as they wish"...yes it is fairly easy to do it with Parse.

Comment: I just extend the class, how do I use masterkey in that case? I have PFUser subclasses in iOS app too.